# Не работает Jquery код при верстке

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, вёрстка

При вёрстке сайта перестала работать JQuery библиотека при написании собственного кода. Карусели Bootstrap работают нормально, а вот, допустим, такой код:

```
$('.go_to').click(function(){ 
    var scroll_el = $(this).attr('href'); 
        if ($(scroll_el).length != 0) {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(scroll_el).offset().top }, 500); 
        }
        return false; 
  });
```

плавной прокрутки не работает, даже банальный addClass не пашет.
Зато в том же файле Js настройка карусели bootstrap срабатывает.
В чем может быть проблема? (Открывал предыдущие недавние проекты такого же вида, но там все нормально)

Comment: Какие версии `Bootstrap` и `jQuery`?

Comment: последние версии

Comment: сюда вставляю в сниппет не работает ... на jsfiddle работает : https://jsfiddle.net/shyapger/

Comment: @МаксимЛенский дело в том что не работает только в этом проекте, идентичный код 4 дня назад работал

Comment: jQuery подключается? Текст ошибки в консоль выводится? `$('.go_to').length` чему равно?

Comment: а ссылку на jQuery откуда берёте ? может быть он не подключился

Comment: @МаксимЛенский <a href="#story" class="nav-link go_to">About</a> тоесть smooth scroll к якорю

Comment: я не про это спросил , а каким образом подключен jQuery ?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Jq подключен так как работают карусельки Bootstrap'a

Comment: @МаксимЛенский <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: странно ... получается у вас на сервере ! хм...

Comment: @МаксимЛенский через cdn также не работает

Comment: Я задал три вопроса, а вы ответили только на один

Comment: @AntonShchyrov нет ошибок в консоли, этот код юзан не раз(копировал), ошибка только в этом проекте, а length это расстояние к секции на которую указывает href

Comment: А может ($(scroll_el).length == 0) ?!?

Comment: @АлексейДрижаков если будет равно 0 то это значит что анимация прокрутки произойдет тогда, когда расстояния к якорю не будет, то есть не произойдет анимации